# Second Order Linear Coupled System of PDE's

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, spectral-theory

I'm trying to solve the following coupled system of linear PDE's

$$
u=(\lambda+2 \mu)\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}u+\mu \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}u +(\lambda+\mu)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial y} v
$$
$$
v=(\lambda+2 \mu)\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}v+\mu \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}v +(\lambda+\mu)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}u
$$

Subject to the initial conditions:
$$
u(x=0,y)=0\\
u(x=L,y)=0\\
\partial_y v(x,y=0)=0\\
\partial_y v(x,y=0)=0
$$

Where $u$ and $v$ are functions of $x,y$ and are at least $C^2$ continuous.

I have tried several methods to solve this problem, but none seem to work. My first instinct is a 2D Fourier Transform which yields:

$$
\tilde{u}=-(2\pi)^2((\lambda+2 \mu)(k_x)^2 \tilde{u}+\mu (k_y)^2 \tilde{u} +(\lambda+\mu)k_xk_y \tilde{v})
$$
$$
\tilde{v}=-(2\pi)^2((\lambda+2 \mu)(\xi_x)^2 \tilde{v}+\mu (\xi_y)^2 \tilde{u} +(\lambda+\mu)\xi_x \xi_y \tilde{u})
$$

Where I have used $F\{u\}=\tilde{u}$ and my Fourier Transform variables as $k$'s and $\xi$'s respectively. However, a really quick inspection shows the above equations can be easily substituted. Solving for $v$ in the second equation and plugging it into the first yields:

$$
\tilde{u}+(\lambda+2\mu)k_x^2 \tilde{u}+\mu k_y^2 \tilde{u} = -(\lambda+\mu)k_xk_y\frac{-(\lambda+\mu)\xi_x\xi_y\tilde{u}}{1+(\lambda+2\mu)k_x^2+\mu k_y^2}
$$

which of course has a $\tilde{u}$ in every term, and assuming $\tilde{u} \neq 0$, and dividing through by $\tilde{u}$ gives no information as to the solution to this PDE. I would like to have an analytic solution, but I'm not sure these equations admit one. However, these are linear PDE's and they don't seem like they should be all that difficult. Do you all have any suggestions? Also, I've tried separation of variables and it leads to a similar conundrum. Ultimately we wish to extract the spectrum from these equations, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that.

Comment: What is the domain of the PDE? Also, there is a symmetry $u \to v$, so why not define a new variable $w = u+v$ which yields $$(\lambda + 2 \mu) w_{xx} + \mu w_{yy} + (\lambda + \mu) w_{xy} - w = 0$$ which seems solveable.

Comment: Good question, $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, I'll check the symmetry solution right now.

Comment: Initial conditions?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I'll include them above rn.

Comment: I tried a quick Mathematica DSolve, and it didn't like it as well, I will try and solve by hand as well.

Comment: I think the symmetry argument is not separable and would have the same problems as the Fourier Transform, in terms of a $\tilde{w}$ would be in every term.

Answer (score 3):

Hint.

We have

$$
(u+v) = (\lambda+2\mu)(u+v)_{xx}+\mu(u+v)_{yy}+(\lambda+\mu)(u+v)_{xy}\\
(u-v) = (\lambda+2\mu)(u-v)_{xx}+\mu(u-v)_{yy}-(\lambda+\mu)(u-v)_{xy}
$$

and then

$$
p = (\lambda+2\mu)p_{xx}+\mu p_{yy}+(\lambda+\mu)p_{xy}\\
q = (\lambda+2\mu)q_{xx}+\mu q_{yy}-(\lambda+\mu)q_{xy}
$$

NOTE

The $p$ equation can be stated as

$$
\left(\frac{\left(-\sqrt{\lambda ^2-2 \lambda  \mu -7 \mu ^2}+\lambda +\mu \right)}{2 \mu }\partial_x+\partial_y\right) \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{\lambda ^2-2
   \lambda  \mu -7 \mu ^2}+\lambda +\mu \right)\partial_x+\mu  \partial_y\right)p = p
$$

The $q$ equation can be stated as

$$
\left(\frac{\left(-\sqrt{\lambda ^2-2 \lambda  \mu -7 \mu ^2}-\lambda -\mu \right)}{2 \mu }\partial_x+\partial_y\right) \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{\lambda ^2-2
   \lambda  \mu -7 \mu ^2}-\lambda -\mu \right)\partial_x+\mu  \partial_y\right)q = q
$$

Comment: This seems like it faces the same problems as above. It's not separable, nor soluble via FT. Could you expand on the etc. a little bit?

Comment: @TylerKharazi Attached an additional step.

Comment: @TylerKharazi Remember that $u = \frac 12(p+q)$ and $v = \frac 12(p-q)$

Comment: Thanks, @Cesareo, I will take a look at that right now.